# R - loop within a loop to extract multiple string combinations for multiple rows in data frame

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, apply

I have a data frame called `tabelao` that looks like the output produced by `dput(head(tabelao)`:

```
structure(list(sequence = c("prot0",  "prot1", "prot2",  "prot3", "prot4",  "prot5"), start = c(282L, 219L, 641L,  355L, 635L, 526L), end = c(325L, 273L, 682L, 370L, 662L, 560L ), length = c(44L, 55L, 42L, 16L, 28L, 35L), AGI = c(1103L, 962L,  869L, 847L, 799L, 736L), AGR = c(25L, 17L, 20L, 52L, 28L, 21L ), epitope = c("SEFKECFKEVNYDMSYFIRTTNPRETKLVQDIWKKZUTKGDWWQL",  "SYAGFEQQRKKFDNPKLKILNVELELKAEKDNPOPRLKDPKQYQSIVDLPOKIIF", "RLEDNPAQWEREKSDEPALLHKELAERRAQQLKJMNRRLANQ",  "AYATLOKIQQWKVRKS", "ASCSVKLGLWKNAPOLQWNALELVPDHP", "KKAERCEDPNAWKGPTNGGPOIUQNAGDGAFYGPK" ), comb_per_epitope = c(30, 41, 28, 2, 14, 21)), .Names = c("sequence",  "start", "end", "length", "AGI", "AGR", "epitope", "comb_per_epitope" ), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I want to do is the following. In each row of `tabelao` I have, on `tabelao$epitope` a string (character) with variable length. From each row (my `tabelao` has 241 rows in total) I want to obtain all possible strings of 15 characters. Note that I do not want palindromic sequences. To get all those sequences (the number of sequences, depending on the length of the string was calculated by length -15 + 1 and it can be seen at `tabelao$comb_per_epitope`)  I used the following loop:

```
combinations <- c() 
for(i in 1:tabelao$comb_per_epitope[1]) {   combinations[i] <- str_sub(string = tabelao$epitope[1], start = i, end
    = i+14) }
```

and I got whtat I wanted i.e. the 30 possible combinations of 15 characters:

```
> combinations
 [1] "SEFKECFKEMNYDMN" "EFKECFKEMNYDMNY" "FKECFKEMNYDMNYF" "KECFKEMNYDMNYFI" "ECFKEMNYDMNYFIR" "CFKEMNYDMNYFIRT" "FKEMNYDMNYFIRTT"
 [8] "KEMNYDMNYFIRTTN" "EMNYDMNYFIRTTNP" "MNYDMNYFIRTTNPT" "NYDMNYFIRTTNPTH" "YDMNYFIRTTNPTHE" "DMNYFIRTTNPTHEK" "MNYFIRTTNPTHEKL"
[15] "NYFIRTTNPTHEKLV" "YFIRTTNPTHEKLVQ" "FIRTTNPTHEKLVQD" "IRTTNPTHEKLVQDI" "RTTNPTHEKLVQDIW" "TTNPTHEKLVQDIWK" "TNPTHEKLVQDIWKK"
[22] "NPTHEKLVQDIWKKL" "PTHEKLVQDIWKKLE" "THEKLVQDIWKKLEA" "HEKLVQDIWKKLEAK" "EKLVQDIWKKLEAKG" "KLVQDIWKKLEAKGD" "LVQDIWKKLEAKGDI"
[29] "VQDIWKKLEAKGDIY" "QDIWKKLEAKGDIYL"
```

But again, I could only manage to do this for the first row. I now want to repeat this over the 241 rows of `tabelao`. I tried to put a loop inside another loop with no success. In addition to this `tabelao`, I also have a `list` called `vetores` which contains, considering each row of `tabelao`, a numeric sequence, starting at 1 and ending at the number of possible combinations, as shown below (I used this list in my loops, as I will show below):

```
> head(vetores)

[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30

[[2]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41

[[3]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28

[[4]]
[1] 1 2

[[5]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14

[[6]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

My "double loop" look like the following:

```
trial <- c() # I'll store the output of each iterations in this object
for(i in 1:nrow(tabelao)){ # I want 241 iterations, which is the length of tabelao
  trial[i] <- for(each in 1:tabelao$comb_per_epitope[i]) {
    str_sub(string = tabelao$epitope[each], start = vetores[[each]][each], end = vetores[[each+14]][each+14])
  }                                                          
}
```

The output was simply NULL:

```
> trial
NULL
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong? I know that looping within a loop is not really advisable. However, I am not that familiar with the `apply` family of functions.

Comment: Try: `Map(function(x,y) substring(x,seq_len(y),seq_len(y)+14),tabelao$epitope,tabelao$comb_per_epitope )`.

Comment: `str_sub` is not a base R function. If you are using any packages, please include them in your question above. Maybe you want the base R `substr` instead?

Comment: yes, sorry, I forgot to mention from which package it is (stringr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below double loop worked for me:

```
trial <- list()  

for(j in 1:nrow(tabelao)){
  combinations <- c()
  for(i in 1:tabelao$comb_per_epitope[j]) {   
     combinations[i] <- str_sub(string = tabelao$epitope[j], 
     start = i,end = i+14)
     trial[[j]] <- combinations
  }

}
```

You should check out apply, sapply, lapply etc... These kind of tasks can be handled much more efficiently that way. Particularly if these data.frames are large. Consider wrapping the string extraction loop in a function and then apply'ing it to your data.frame

For example you could also achieve this using the below:

```
# Wrap the string extraction in a function
string15 <- function(df){

   # Define combinations as vector 
   combinations <- c() 
   for(i in 1:df$comb_per_epitope) { # Use for loop to loop through       combinations  
       combinations[i] <- str_sub(string = df$epitope, start = i, end
                                                                      =  i+14) 
       }
   # Return the combinations
   return(combinations)
}

# Split your dataframe by sequence to get a list of dataframes where  each element of the list represents a row of the data.frame
tabelao.splits <- split(tabelao, as.factor(tabelao$sequence))

# Define a list to hold the results and lapply your function
res <- list()
res <- lapply(tabelao.splits, string15)
```

Comment: Great, it worked for me too. Indeed I recently had a look at the `apply` family functions and they indeed sometimes handle data more easily than loops.

Comment: Glad it worked, the apply family of functions definitely take a bit of getting used to but it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

I d' use `rollapply` from `zoo` package. In this case, we split each string by `''` and apply the `rollapply` function in each string. The `rollapply` applies the function `paste` to rolling indices of each string. So for each string, it pastes [1:15], [2:16], [3:17], and so on.
We finally use `Map` with `length<-`(as a function, hence the backticks) to set the length based on your `comb_per_epitope` variable.

```
library(zoo)
Map(`length<-`, lapply(strsplit(tabelao$epitope, ''), function(i)
                      rollapply(i, 15, by = 1, paste, collapse = '')), tabelao$comb_per_epitope)
```

Comment: Although I am not familiar at all with this function, it did the job. Thanks

Comment: It basically applies a function to rolling indices, so what it does here it applies `paste` to string 1[1:15], [2:16], [3, 17], etc...

Comment: that looks handy, will have a closer look